# How can I say this in japanese?

Tags: translation

My friend who is Japanese asked me where to meet him. I want to tell him " next to Tim Hortons like last time" Do I say "Tim hortons no chikai zenkai mitai" Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is:

> zenkai mitai ni Tim Hortons no soba de. (前回みたいに Tim Hortons のそばで。)

First, `chikai` neither is grammatical here, nor means "next to". It means *near* or *around*, that means it could also be a place one block away from Tim Hortons. `soba` is the right word "where beside" (it's a noun). An alternative is `tonari` ("next door"), if where you're mentioning is another building, house or park etc.

Next, English language sometimes modifies from behind: "*right* next to TH" vs. "next to TH *like last time*", but Japanese doesn't do this. We always say "like-last-time next to TH".

Lastly, it's better to put `de` in the end. Your English actually means "Let's meet next to --.", only without saying the "Let's meet" part. Likewise in Japanese, "-- no soba de aou" without "aou" must be "-- no soba de", otherwise your friend would be subconsciously baffled around 0.2 seconds about what he should do next to Tim Hortons.

Comment: How about using [前]{まえ} or この前?

Comment: @user1016 この前 means earlier.
「Tim Hortonsの前で」 could work though.